# Run yewtube as systemd process?

Tags: linux, bash, audio

I was trying to run a `yt` ([yewtube](https://pypi.org/project/yewtube/)) command at system start.
I got one service for starting desktop, because my setup is headless.
This works and start display (also for vnc).

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 10 && /usr/bin/x0vncserver -display :0  -rfbport 5900 -passwordfile /home/suomi/.vnc/passwd &'
```

and command for `yt` service looks like this

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 20 && yt playurl https://www.youtube.com/'

When I run this command as root user from desktop's terminal it works and starts `clementine` player to stream video. When I try to run this as `systemd` process it shows it completed and service is `loaded` but not `clementine` process is spawned. Can someone show me way to start it properly please?

This is the code

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Audio service
After=syslog.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
After=x11-common.service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=suomi
Group=suomi
WorkingDirectory=/home/suomi
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sleep 20 && yt playurl https://www.youtube.com/<some link>'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(got here 20 sec for desktop service to start)

And this is status

```
● audio.service - Audio service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/audio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2023-02-26 12:49:39 JST; 16min ago
  Process: 4707 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c sleep 20 && yt playurl ...
```

**UPDATE**: I was wrong, it wont start as root user even from Desktop's terminal. Only when I use my user.
Is this because Clementine is not installed for root?

Comment: `process is spammed.` .. please explain definition 100234 of "spammed".  Didn't anyone watch Monty Python?  Spammed seems to mean more and more things.

Comment: Probably "spawned".

Comment: I'm not really sure `Type=forking` is right. It would seem to me that the default type `simple` is the right one to use in this case. (But well I don't know much this yt/yewtube.) Anyway, the problem might be due to missing (correct) `DISPLAY` (and `XAUTHORITY`) env var ([`Environment=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)).

Comment: Also I wonder if there would be potential problem for process spawned with system service to reach pulse/pipewire. (Btw since you specified `User=` and `Group=`, I don't think you should take what happens in a root shell / terminal as a reference.)